# Full screen mode across multiple monitors on Yosemite

Tags: macos, display, fullscreen, gpu

I have a mid 2014 15" MacBook Pro Retina connected to 3 1920x1080 monitors on thunderbolt+HMDI ports (NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB). The monitors are in portrait mode with total screen resolution of 3240x1920.

I would like to be able to make an application run in full screen across all three monitors using the full screen mode introduced in Yosemite. At present, I can scale a window to almost fit the full screen manually. Is it possible to make this happen with the green full screen button in the gui?

Answer (score 1):

Fullscreen only works on the desktop (space) the application is inside of at the moment. Since each display has their own spaces, the app will not cross over into the others unless you manually resize it to fit.

Comment: I have "Displays have separate spaces" turned off in Settings. All three monitors are displaying in a single "space" (otherwise I wouldn't be able to scale the window beyond  a single monitor).  Is there some way to alter the fullscreen dimensions so that resizing occupies the whole screen (3240x1920) rather than just one monitor (1080x1920)? Perhaps this would work if the resize is done from screen 1 and across screens 2 and 3?